# Webmasters Birthday Celebration?

Tags: discussion

Did you know Pro Webmaster's anniversary of its graduation is coming up on **13 October**? Congratulations!

How about a fun activity to stir things up a little? After a year of great Q&A, **we'd like the opportunity to "give back" for everyone's hard work.**

Anniversary events area a great way to spark some interest in the extracurricular activity in your site (more meta participation). An “anniversary event" can be just about anything. Take a look at [**Super User’s 2nd Birthday Super Contest**](http://blog.superuser.com/2011/08/19/super-users-2nd-birthday-super-contest/) or at the [**Unix & Linux Birthday Bash**](https://unix.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/873/a-contest-to-cleanup-old-abandoned-questions) for inspiration. It doesn’t have to be a contest. Dream up whatever *you* feel the community will find interesting, and go for it.

Start a meta post or chat event to work out the details. Rally support for your event and bring it to our attention through your moderator team! We're really interested in community-led initiatives, so let’s just say, if you can work out the details, we’re very motivated to say “Let's go!”

Either way, congratulations on making it two years. :)

Comment: One really cool thing that one of our sites has done is organize an analog-space meetup. Feel free to get creative!

Answer (score 4):

A cool thing to do would be to get together on the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/524/webmasters) sometime. If other people are interested, then we could set up a time and put a notice on the community bulletin.

Comment: +1 - I like this idea. :)

Comment: Yes, a chat will get more ideas than justing thinking of things to type in an answer box.

Comment: So did anything happen? I was probably recovering from jetlag on Saturday ;)

Comment: @DisgruntledGoat nothing happened, but if you wanted to organise one, I would add a system message and put it on the community bulletin, and I would try to show up. I feel like this would be a good thing to do.